# Same consumer group (s3 sink connector) across two different kafka connect cluster

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, confluent-platform, s3-kafka-connector

I'm migrating Kafka connectors from an ECS cluster to a new cluster running on Kubernetes. I successfully migrated the Postgres source connectors over by deleting them and recreating them on the exact replication slots. They keep writing to the same topics in the same Kafka cluster. And the S3 connector in the old cluster continues to read from those and write records into S3. Everything works as usual.

But now to move the AWS s3 sink connectors, I first created a non-critical s3 connector in the new cluster with the same name as the one in the old cluster. I was going to wait a few minutes before deleting the old one to avoid missing data. To my surprise, it looks like (based on the UI provided by akhq.io) the one worker on that new s3 connector joins with the existing same consumer group. I was fully expecting to have duplicated data. Based on the [Confluent doc](https://docs.confluent.io/home/connect/self-managed/userguide.html#kconnect-internal-topics),

> All Workers in the cluster use the same three internal topics to share
> connector configurations, offset data, and status updates. For this
> reason all distributed worker configurations in the same Connect
> cluster must have matching config.storage.topic, offset.storage.topic,
> and status.storage.topic properties.

So from this "same Connect cluster", I thought having the same consumer group id only works within the same connect cluster. But from my observation, it seems like you could have multiple consumers in different clusters belonging to the same consumer group?

Based on this [article](https://www.conduktor.io/kafka/kafka-consumer-groups-and-consumer-offsets#Kafka-Consumer-Offsets-2) `__consumer_offsets` is used by consumers, and unlike other hidden "offset" related topics, it doesn't have any cluster name designation.

Does that mean I could simply create S3 sink connectors in the new Kubernetes cluster and then delete the ones in the ECS cluster without duplicating or missing data then (as long as they have the same name -> same consumer group)? I'm not sure if this is the right pattern people usually use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not familiar with using a Kafka Connect Cluster but I understand that it is a cluster of connectors that is independent of the Kafka cluster.

In that case, since the connectors are using the same Kafka cluster and you are just moving them from ECS to k8s, it should work as you describe. The consumer offsets information and the [internal kafka connect offsets information](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/connect/design.html#internal-kconnect-offsets) is stored in the Kafka cluster, so it doesn't really matter where the connectors run as long as they connect to the same Kafka cluster. They should restart from the same position or behave as additional replicas of the same connector regardless of where ther are running.

Comment: Thanks! Your response makes sense. After re-reading some docs and thinking about it I was confident enough to migrate the s3 connectors today that way!! 
Since the S3 sink connector gets its group id named after "connect-<connector_name>" and each connector in the same connect cluster has to have a unique name, the case of having two consumers in the same group usually wouldn't come up. In this case, we have two different clusters so it's a unique situation. But each connector is just a group of worker tasks, and they're the ones being assigned to consumer groups.